# Passing Array to WebMethod using jquery ajax is not working in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I am trying to send all gridview records to webmethod using jquery ajax but it is not working. Here is my code

```
function Save() {
            var TableData = new Array();

            $('[id*=GridView1] tr').each(function (row, tr) {
                TableData[row] = {
                    "Sr"    : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()
                  , "RollNo": $(tr).find('.RollNo').val()
                  , "Name"  : $(tr).find('.Name').val()
                  , "Marks" : $(tr).find('.Marks').val()
                }
            });
                        TableData.shift();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "TestPage.aspx/SaveData",
                data: "{Data:'" + JSON.stringify(TableData) + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
```

and Code Behind

```
  [WebMethod]    
    public static string SaveData(List<string> Data)
    {      
       //My Code
        return "Success";
    }
```

Help me guys....

Comment: Does the control hit the `webmethod`?? Did you debug?

Comment: what is the issue? as i see you have a `dataType: "json",` and you are not returning back a json response. so i can suggest you to remove it or change it to `dataType: "text",`

Comment: I debug the code. it's not calling webmethod.

Comment: also why `TableData.shift();`?

Comment: Hi @Jai I used dataType: "text", but it's still not working. TableData.shift(); is  used to remove the header row.

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi check the network tab see if the ajax url is there.

Comment: I am really really sorry guys. I have posted wrong server side code. Please check my edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That must be throwing a `500 inetrnal server` error because of type mismatch:-

```
 public static string SaveData(string Data)
    {      
       //My Code
        return "Success";
    }
```

You are passing a `JSON` string so you should expect the same at server side and then deserialize it into a .Net object.

**Update:**

You can use the [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) class:-

```
public static string SaveData(string Data)
{      
   JavaScriptSerializer json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   List<GridData> mygridData = json.Deserialize<List<GridData>>(Data);
   return "Success";
}
```

You are not passing a `List<String>` first of all from client side, you are passing a javascript object with properties. So to map it in .Net you will have to define an equivalent `Type` like this:-

```
public class GridData
{
    public string Sr{ get; set; }
    public string RollNo{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Marks{ get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rahul Singh.  I want to receive an array in server side. So how can I deserialize it into a .Net object ?

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi - It's a class which will store data at server side, I have updated.